# Css div in another div image center

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <div id="inner">
    <div id="wrap">
      <img src="images/thumb/3.jpeg"/> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

And the following style applied to it:

```
body{

    background:url(pattern/pattern1.png);
}
#inner{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:#669;
    text-align:center;
}

#wrap{

    width:50%;

    margin:0 auto;

}
```

The problem is that the image it always stay top-centered in inner div but i want it to be in center of wrap

**!--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Still same problem  and heres the code in jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/RNhvz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the margin to the image element directly: [JSFiddle example1](http://jsfiddle.net/RNhvz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin: 0 auto` is part of your problem.

Do you know the height of your image?  I presume it is under 400px.  Change the `0` in your `margin` style to half the difference between 400 and the height of your image.

For example, if your image is 200px in height, change your `margin` style to:

`margin: 100px auto`

(400 - 200) / 2 = 100

Answer (score 0):

If your #inner is always going to have 400px height then just use this code:

```
#inner{
    /* Your code: */
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:#669;
    text-align:center;

    /* Solution part I. */
    line-height: 400px;
}

/* Solution part II. */
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

That way an image will be centred both vertically and horizontally and - what's more important - this solution doesn't require you to know the image size. And you don't need the #wrap div. You can keep in in your HTML syntax but there's no need for width and margin rules of this element.

Here's the working code: http://tinkerbin.com/YOjVvnVZ.